# Issue with Django logout URL redirection

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-login

I have configured login and logout redirect setting in Django settings as below -

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/locations/'
```

However, after logging out the redirection is done on the **next=** parameter, ie., the url is redirected to the same page from where logout is clicked.

For the reference, here is login/logout URL from my *urls.py* -

```
url(r'^', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

**PS**: I am using Django 1.11 & DRF 3.7.3

Comment: Do you want to logout from your django app or the DRF's browseable API?

Comment: I want to logout from thr browsable API.

Answer (score 2):

The solution above didn't work for me with Django 2.1+

After looking into the logout function source code

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
  logout(request)
  # Redirect to a success page.
```

I wound up creating a custom logout view that calls the logout function and defines a redirect page

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def logout_view(request):
  logout(request)
  return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGOUT_URL, request.path))
```

Just call this view in your urls.py instead of "logout"

```
urlpatterns = [   
  path('accounts/logout/', views.logout_view),
]
```

And now a LOGOUT_URL redirect in settings.py will actually work

```
LOGOUT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL was not always working.

Solved it inside my myapp/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'next_page': '/login/'}, name='logout'),
]
```

Then in my desired template I inserted a link to: /'myapp'/logout/

You could as well define it in your main urls.py

Comment: I will try this and i am sure this would work. However, is there a way to do this using one URL as i have mentioned?

Comment: I tried it and it seems I would have to add a template for logout and login. How would I use the in-built Django login template? Also this way I do not get option to logout from browsable API. Something like this - https://i.imgur.com/oCi1jwc.png

Comment: Django does not include a built in login template. Only the view. But initial code you would find it in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#all.authentication.views.registration/login.html

Answer (score 0):

you can add the below line in the settings.py to redirect to the login page if you're using Django in-built authentication.

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ='/accounts/login/'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).